# Is there a way to programmatically access Azure continuous webjob function invocations?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, webjob

Is there a way to programmatically access Azure continuous webjob function invocations?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite yet, but it's on the way.
We're exposing some logging APIs (preview at https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging/ILogReader.cs ) for this.

This is being tracked by this issue: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/880

Comment: great thanks, will have a look. Is this relevant at all though http://robertmayer.se/2016/04/28/azure-function-app-logs/? I can't see AzureFunctionsLogTable though..

Comment: That's basically reverse engineering the log format - which is brittle and subject to change. For example, the information on that page is already out of date. That's why we need a formal API.  If you have specific requests, feel free to comment on the GitHub issue.

Comment: Where would I look in storage to find invocation log? table mentioned on that page "AzureFunctionsLogTable" doesn't exist..